# Count specific dates [R]

Tags: r

Got a huge data frame, with a column full of dates. Like this:

```
Date
2014-01-02
2014-01-02
2014-01-02
2014-01-03
2014-01-03
2014-02-01
2014-02-01
2014-02-02
2014-02-02
```

I want to build an extra column, containing the number of days that appeared in the month (! the data contains multiple years data, so there are more then 1 Januaries, Februaries etc.). Just like this:

```
Date           Count
2014-01-02      5
2014-01-02      5
2014-01-02      5
2014-01-03      5
2014-01-03      5
2014-02-01      4
2014-02-01      4
2014-02-02      4
2014-02-02      4
```

My solution is poor. I used the filter option (from dplyr)to filter the specific months, and then count them. But because it cost a lot of time, and because I want to do this automatically I'm looking for a more sustainable solution.

Comment: Do you group specific months (eg. January) from different years? Do you have only data from a specific year?

Comment: I got data from multiple years.. so I got multiple Januaries, which I want to count separately.

Comment: It would be much better for you to post a more representative example of your dataset then. In order to minimise number of bugs when you try to apply the posted solutions to your real dataset :-)

Comment: Make sense! I will update my example. Appreciate the feedback.

Comment: I've already changed my answer to take the year into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with base `R`:

```
d <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text=
"Date
2014-01-02
2014-01-02
2014-01-02
2014-01-03
2014-01-03
2014-02-01
2014-02-01
2014-02-02
2014-02-02")

d$count <- ave(!is.na(d$Date), substr(d$Date, 1,7), FUN=sum)
d
```

`substr(d$Date, 1,7)` extracts the first seven characters from the strings in `d$Date` (i.e. the part with year and month, e.g. `2014-01`). The result is used for grouping in `ave()`

Here is a solution with `data.table`:

```
library("data.table")
D <- fread(
"Date
2014-01-02
2014-01-02
2014-01-02
2014-01-03
2014-01-03
2014-02-01
2014-02-01
2014-02-02
2014-02-02")

D[, count:=.N, substr(Date, 1, 7)]
D
```

Comment: Perfect, it worked. But can you explain what you are doing with the 1,7 part?

Comment: I edited my answer. Also read the documentation of `substr()`, i.e. `help("substr")`

Answer (score 2):

If you have your dates in POSIXlt format,  the month is built in and you can just make a table to reference.

```
Date = as.POSIXlt(c('2014-01-02',
'2014-01-02',
'2014-01-02',
'2014-01-03',
'2014-01-03',
'2014-02-01',
'2014-02-01',
'2014-02-02',
'2014-02-02'))

table(Date$mon)[as.character(Date$mon)]
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 
5 5 5 5 5 4 4 4 4
```

The 0/1 row is just the column names.  In POSIX January is month 0, Feb is month 1, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already using `dplyr`...

```
df <- read.table(text = "Date
2014-01-02
                 2014-01-02
                 2014-01-02
                 2014-01-03
                 2014-01-03
                 2014-02-01
                 2014-02-01
                 2014-02-02
                 2014-02-02", header = T)
df

library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(ym = format(as.Date(Date, "%Y-%m-%d"), "%Y-%m")) %>% 
  mutate(Count = n()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-ym)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've changed your posted example in order to take into account the year of each month, as you want to count them separately (specified in your comments):

```
df = read.table(text = "
Date
2014-01-02
2014-01-02
2014-01-02
2014-01-03
2015-01-03
2014-02-01
2014-02-01
2014-02-02
2015-02-02",
header=T)

library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Date = ymd(Date)) %>%     # update to a datetime variable (if needed)
  group_by(Month = month(Date),    # for each month and year
           Year = year(Date)) %>%
  mutate(N = n()) %>%              # count number of rows/appearances
  ungroup() %>%                    # forget the grouping
  select(-Month, -Year)            # remove help variables

# # A tibble: 9 x 2
#         Date     N
#       <date> <int>
# 1 2014-01-02     4
# 2 2014-01-02     4
# 3 2014-01-02     4
# 4 2014-01-03     4
# 5 2015-01-03     1
# 6 2014-02-01     3
# 7 2014-02-01     3
# 8 2014-02-02     3
# 9 2015-02-02     1
```

Comment: I think you can avoid creating two variables, namely year and month. You could write something like `group = format(Date, "%Y-%m")` in group_by.  This is enough to create unique levels of a grouping variable.

Comment: That is correct. I could also paste my two variables in one (character string). I always think about further processing in case they decide not to take year into account and they could group only by one of the variables (eg. month).